# How to add mail recipient in android calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am trying to add event that can synchronize with the mail account. I could synchronize the event with mail but How to add participant mail id programmatically into the calendar?
I am searching for past 3 days for the answer through internet.
Any Help is highly appreciated and Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help you. It is the Edit Event activity of android's default calendar. please search this class for "Attendee" and you will find where it is being set and used.

[Here is the code, click please](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/calendar/EditEvent.java.html)